# Как избавиться от ветки if else при десериализации

Tags: c#, десериализация

В программу приходят запросы из внешней среды, тип запроса я узнаю исходя из поля type, как написать данный код в объектно-ориентированном стиле, и возможно ли это?

```
public IMessage ConvertJsonToObject(string request)
    {
        if (request.Contains(@"""type"":""recognitionResult"""))
            return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<RecognitionResult>(request);

        else if (request.Contains(@"""type"":""photo"""))
            return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<PhotoOnRequest>(request);

        else if (request.Contains(@"""type"":""requestCurrentPhoto"""))
            return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<PhotoRequest>(request);

        else if (request.Contains(@"""type"":""requestPhoto"""))
            return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<DateTimePhotoRequest>(request);

        else if (request.Contains(@"""type"":""recognitionChanStatus"""))
            return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<StatusChannel>(request);

        else if (request.Contains(@"""type"":""recognitionKeyStatus"""))
            return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<StatusSecurityKey>(request);

        else if (request.Contains(@"""type"":""recognitionVideoStatus"""))
            return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<StatusVideo>(request);
        else
            _logger.WriteToExceptionLog(
                new Exception($"Не удалось десериализовать входящее сообщение {request}"));

        return null;
    }
```

Пример запроса:

```
 /// <summary>
/// Запрос текущей фотографии
/// </summary>
public class PhotoRequest : IMessage
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Идентификатор камеры
    /// </summary>
    public string camera { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Название и версия протокола
    /// </summary>
    public string protocol { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Тип сообщения
    /// </summary>
    public string type { get; set; }
    
    public string GetJson()
    {
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
    }

    public virtual string GetLogInfo(TransferType transferType, string address)
    {
        return $"{transferType}: {type}," +
               $" Адрес: {address}," +
               $" Камера: {camera}," +
               $" Время создания запрашиваемого фото: {DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss_fff")}";
    }
}
```

Пример сериализованного запроса:

`{"camera":"Context1","protocol":"protocol1","type":"requestCurrentPhoto"}`

Comment: Пожалуйста, вставьте код текстом. Совсем не хочется перепечатывать его с картинки, чтобы дать ответ. Так же покажите пример ответа от сервера, нужно понять, где лежит `type`, чтобы дать правильный ответ.

Comment: Пример ответа от сервера в json формате, или класс?

Comment: можно и то и другое, так будет еще точнее, все классы не надо, одного достаточно `type` у них в одно месте

Comment: Всегда указывайте (ставьте метку), какую библиотеку используете для работы с Json.

Comment: Json.Net имеет настройку [TypeNameHandling](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeTypeNameHandling.htm). Вы можете поменять формат Json? Если вы его создаёте или можете связаться с теми, кто может изменить код его создания, то используйте эту настройку.

Comment: `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` `JsonSerializer.Deserialize` мне кажется, что лучше выбрать что-то одно. Зачем использовать разные сериализаторы в разных частях кода?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Определять тип лучше с помощью десереализации в модель, которая подходит под все типы сообщений.

Как-то так получится.

```cs
public class MessageTypeModel
{
    [JsonPropertyName("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
}

public Type GetMessageType(string json)
{
    return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MessageTypeModel>(json).Type switch
    {
        "recognitionResult" => typeof(RecognitionResult),
        "photo" => typeof(PhotoOnRequest),
        "requestCurrentPhoto" => typeof(PhotoRequest),
        "requestPhoto" => typeof(DateTimePhotoRequest),
        "recognitionChanStatus" => typeof(StatusChannel),
        "recognitionKeyStatus" => typeof(StatusSecurityKey),
        "recognitionVideoStatus" => typeof(StatusVideo),
        _ => throw new Exception($"Не удалось десериализовать входящее сообщение {json}")
    };
}

public IMessage ConvertJsonToObject(string request)
{
    try
    {
        return (IMessage)JsonSerializer.Deserialize(request, GetMessageType(request));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.WriteToExceptionLog(ex);
    }
    return null;
}
```