# Как десериализировать Json в Class с помощью Newtonsoft. Если элемент Json может быть как String и быть как составной объект

Tags: c#, json

Есть следующий код Json

```
{
"contact": [
    {
        "verified": true,
        "comment": null,
        "type": {
            "id": "cell",
            "name": "Мобильный телефон"
        },
        "preferred": true,
        "value": {
            "country": "7",
            "city": "123",
            "number": "4567890",
            "formatted": "+71234567890"
        }
    },
    {
        "type": {
            "id": "email",
            "name": "Эл. почта"
        },
        "preferred": false,
        "value": "applicant@example.com"
    }
]}
```

И частично написанный class для десериализации

```
public class HrImportCandidateResponse
{
    [JsonProperty("contact")]
    public HrImportCandidateContact[] Contact { get; set; }
}

public class HrImportCandidateContact
{
    [JsonProperty("verified")]
    public bool Verified { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("comment")]
    public string Comment { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("type")]
    public HrImportCandidateContactType Type { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("preferred")]
    public bool Preferred { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("value")]
    public HrImportCandidateContactValue Value { get; set; }
}

public class HrImportCandidateContactType
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class HrImportCandidateContactValue
{
    [JsonProperty("country")]
    public string Country { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("city")]
    public string City { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("number")]
    public string Number { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("formatted")]
    public string Formatted { get; set; }
}
```

Вопрос в том как сказать десериализатору Newtonsoft
Что у объекта contact может два разных типа объекта.
Где `type.id` = cell там у него value объект.
Где `type.id` = email там у него value string.

Comment: Перечитайте пост, с ним что-то не так.

Comment: @aepot Привет, спасибо. Сейчас поправлю.

Comment: Поправил код в описании

Comment: Вот был [похожий вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1276361/373567) - оно? Правда там `System.Text.Json`, но сути не меняет.

Comment: @aepot Я тоже сделал кривое решение, с конвертацией в объект, потом через цикл смотреть тип и создавать класс.
Но я хотел бы увидеть как это можно сделать через модель NewtonSoft. Чтобы я имею ввиду переопределить где то сам десериализатора, чтобы его научить работать с таким типом.

Comment: Кастомный конвертер. Штука не простая, но думаю его вы хотите.